# Apache directory listing with upload button and search textbox

Tags: html, css, apache

So i have a server, with apache 2 - running a directory browser(i think it's called. Where i can access my files), as my own dropbox server. However it does how some limitations, when i'm at school for instance, and i wish to upload a project, i gotta send it with email to myself to upload it, i cant delete or anything. So i wanted to add a delete button(least important), i wanted to add a search function since the files are beginning to stack up. I would also like an upload button. I didn't really understand apache, i followed a tutorial for the server. I have a very basic html knowledge, and i have tried and tried to create it myself, and i have been searching for a loooong time(trust me).

So could anyone post a solution/tutorial/tip or anything useful? Please try to help me instead of answering with rude answers. I'm 15 and hoping to get these features up and running as soon as possible. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the open source FTP FileZilla software https://filezilla-project.org/ instead?

Comment: Thats what i mainly use for uploading files, but that doesn't work at schools and places like that where i need the upload functionality. They have this school networks with intranets and tight security systems. RDP doesn't even work. Only thing i can to access server at this point is HTTP